# How can I transform a List <string> to a Dictionary<string, int>?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How can I transform a `List <string>` to a `Dictionary<string, int>`?

This should be number from zero to n.

Comment: what is `o` and what is `n`?

Comment: @Qaesar, an edit has been made that specifies `Dictionary<string, int>`. Is that what you actually require? Or is it `Dictionary<int, string>`?  In my answer, the `int` counter is the key, which is not correct per the edit...

Comment: @ Jonathon Reinhart...yes I just noted that .. Then how your code fill the question need please??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ToDictionary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx) to create a `Dictionary` from any `IEnumerable`.

```
var list = new List<string>() { "Foo", "Bar", "Spam" };

// TKey is int, TValue is string
int i = 0;
Dictionary<int,string> dict1 = list.ToDictionary( _ => i++ );          

// TKey is string, TValue is int
i = 0;
Dictionary<string,int> dict2 = list.ToDictionary( x => x, _ => i++ );
```

The lambda passed to `ToDictionary` is the `keySelector`. Usually you use this to *select* a property from the items in the `IEnumerable` to be the key, but here, we use it to provide a count.

**Edit:** The second version uses two selectors. The first is the key. By providing a `x => x` lambda, we are just using the string that came from the list. The second selector is the value. Here, we are providing the counter, `i`.

---

**Performance**

I decided to test out the performance of my method versus pst's method.

Test Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    const int N = 1000000;
    const int M = 10;
    Stopwatch s;

    // Generate test list of strings.
    var list = Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(n => n.ToString());

    // Just so it's enumerated once before.
    var ar = list.ToArray(); 

    // Try Jonathon's method M times.
    s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int x = 0; x < M; x++) {
        int i = 0;
        //var dict1 = list.ToDictionary(_ => i++);    // Before question edit
        var dict1 = list.ToDictionary(x => x, _ => i++);
    }
    s.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Jonathon's i++ method took {0} ms", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    // Try pst's method M times.
    s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int x = 0; x < M; x++) {
        var dict2 = list.Select((v, j) => new {v, j}).ToDictionary(p => p.v, p => p.j);
    }
    s.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("psts' Select() method took {0} ms", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
Jonathon's i++ method took 3005 ms
pst's Select() method took 5019 ms
```

Output (After question edit):

```
Jonathon's i++ method took 3521 ms
pst's Select() method took 5103 ms
```

In conclusion, it appears that there is a roughly 40% improvement by using a counter instead of creating the intermediate, anonymous-typed objects.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov Your solution was correct, except the `IndexOf` call is expensive, when all you really need is a counter.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, I've always been thinking so (that code would work, but is expensive), but never really tried to improve it...So that `IndexOf` has no right to be posted near an answer like yours! I never say this, but I'd give you more than one upvote this easily

Comment: @Qaesar Simple. Use the same version of `ToDictionary` that pst is using. If you look it up in the MSDN docs, you'll see that it takes *two* selectors, one for the key, one for the value. I've edited my answer to show both.

Comment: @ Jonathon Reinhart.. So which is faster ?? using your second code or pst  code ??

Comment: @Qaesar Which do you think it will be? And also, why don't you test it yourself? The code is right there, just make the trivial change and try it!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that each item maps to the key and and `n` represents the index in the source, then:

```
var dict = list
    .Select((v, i) => new {v, i})
    .ToDictionary(p => p.v, p => p.i);
```

I like this approach because, while the temporary anonymous type is a little wonky, it's a self-contained side-effect free expression.

(This will throw an exception if there are any duplicate items in the source list.)

Comment: I like this, because it's using the index provided by the `Select()`, however, I feel like the extra object creation (anonymous type), just to be passed to `ToDictionary` makes it not worth it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart When I have a performance test-case, then I'll care :) I deal with very little "performance-critial" code, as my run-time time is often dominated by other factors, so I am not jaded on the subject yet.

Comment: +1. If you like Tuple you can use `Tuple.Create(v,i)` instead of `new {v,i}` (result is identical).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart [ref](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/); I dislike the "famous" quote from that excerpt but am rather fond of the less-known surrounding 97/3 context

Comment: @pst - Sure, I agree that prematurely optimizing things is never a good idea. But here, my code is actually simpler, and it is plain to see that yours incurs an intermediate object creation penalty where mine does not. It's not like I went out of my way to make it faster - it's just less code.  There's a difference between "prematurely optimizing" code, and just trying to write good code in the first place.  All this said, I'm by no means saying there's anything wrong with your approach.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I avoided the use of that phrasing on purpose :-) My coding style is that I will do my very best to avoid side-effects in LINQ expressions; I'm the kind who insists on `foreach` to capture such intent, even if very localized, but `foreach` doesn't really fit this case well at all.